# Based on the Checkbox value we display the next step

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

Here is my code.........

```
<div class="box-content">
<div id="Div1" class="wizard">
    <li data-target="#step1" class="active"><span class="badge badge-info">1</span></li>
    <li data-target="#step2"><span class="badge">2</span></li>
    <li data-target="#step3"><span class="badge">3</span></li>
    <li data-target="#step4"><span class="badge">4</span></li>
    <li data-target="#step5"><span class="badge">5</span></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="actions">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-prev"><i class="icon-arrow-left"></i>Prev</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-next" data-last="Finish">Next<i class="icon-arrow-right"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="step-content">
    <div class="step-pane active" id="Div2" runat="server">
        <div class="control-group ">
            <div class="controls">
                <h1>Create a new event<asp:textbox id="TextBox1" runat="server" cssclass="control-label"></asp:textbox>
                    starting on 
                    <asp:textbox id="TextBox2" runat="server" style="color: #727272 !important; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 100;" cssclass="span2 input-xlarge datepicker"></asp:textbox>
                    for
                    <asp:dropdownlist id="DropDownList1" runat="server" style="color: #727272 !important; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 100;" cssclass="span1" onselectedindexchanged="EventDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged" autopostback="true">
                        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
                     </asp:dropdownlist>
                    days. </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="step-pane" id="Div3" runat="server">
            <div class="control-group ">
                <h1>Matching making will be held on the following days:
                                               <br />
                    <br />
                </h1>
                <div class="row-fluid" runat="server" id="Div4">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="step-pane" id="Div5">

            <h1>Matchmaking starts at 
                <asp:dropdownlist id="DropDownList2" runat="server" style="color: #727272 !important; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 100;" cssclass="span2">
                     <asp:ListItem Text="9:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Text="9:30 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Text="10:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Text="10:30 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Text="11:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Text="11:30 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Text="12:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Text="12:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Text="1:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Text="1:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Text="2:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Text="2:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Text="3:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Text="3:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Text="4:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                     <asp:ListItem Text="4:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                 </asp:dropdownlist>
                and ends at
                <asp:dropdownlist id="DropDownList3" runat="server" style="color: #727272 !important; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 100;" cssclass="span2">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="9:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="9:30 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="10:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="10:30 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="11:00 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="11:30 AM"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="12:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="12:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="1:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="1:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="2:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="2:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="3:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="3:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="4:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="4:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="5:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="5:30 PM"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="6:00 PM"></asp:ListItem>

                 </asp:dropdownlist>
                .<br /><br />
                Each slot is 
                <asp:dropdownlist id="DropDownList4" runat="server" autopostback="True" style="color: #727272 !important; font-size: 24px; font-weight: 100;" cssclass="span2" onselectedindexchanged="SlotDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged">

                    <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>25</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>30</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>35</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>40</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>45</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>50</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>55</asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem>60</asp:ListItem>
                 </asp:dropdownlist>
                minutes long. </h1>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="step-pane" id="Div6">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="control-group ">
                <h1>The following slots are available for Matchmaking.
                                            <br />
                </h1>
                <div class="alert alert-info">
                    Turn off any slots you wish to disable.
                </div>
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="span6">
                        <h1>
                            <asp:label id="Label1" runat="server"></asp:label>
                        </h1>
                        <div class="task low" runat="server" id="Div7">
                        </div>

                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="step-pane" id="Div8">
        <h1>Your event is ready!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code Behind is

```
    protected void SlotDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Date_label.Text = StartDate_TB.Text;
        DateTime start = DateTime.Parse(StartTime_DDL.SelectedItem.Text);
        DateTime end = DateTime.Parse(EndTime_DDL.SelectedItem.Text);
        double duration = double.Parse(SlotDuration_DDL.SelectedItem.Text);
        string header = "<div class='priority low'><span><strong>{0}</strong></span></div>";
        string header1 = "<div class='priority medium'><span><strong>{0}</strong></span></div>";
        string morning = "";
        string afternon = "";
        bool doneMornHeader = false, doneAfternoonHeader = false;
        while (true)
        {
            DateTime dtNext = start.AddMinutes(duration);
            if (start > end || dtNext > end)
                break;
            if (start < DateTime.Parse("12:00 PM"))
            {
                if (!doneMornHeader)
                {
                    Label head = new Label();
                    head.Text = string.Format(header, "Morning");
                    this.Timediv.Controls.Add(head);
                    doneMornHeader = true;
                }
                morning = start.ToShortTimeString() + "-" + dtNext.ToShortTimeString();
                Label lbl = new Label();
                lbl.Text = morning;
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();

                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='desc'>"));
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='title'>"));
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(lbl);
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='make-switch span5 pull-right' data-on='success'>"));
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(cb);
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));

                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
            }
            else
            {
                if (!doneAfternoonHeader)
                {
                    Label head = new Label();
                    head.Text = string.Format(header1, "Afternoon");
                    this.Timediv.Controls.Add(head);
                    doneAfternoonHeader = true;
                }
                afternon = start.ToShortTimeString() + "-" + dtNext.ToShortTimeString();
                Label lbl1 = new Label();
                lbl1.Text = afternon;
                CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox();

                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='desc'>"));
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='title'>"));
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(lbl1);
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='make-switch span5 pull-right' data-on='success'>"));
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(cb1);
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));

                this.Timediv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));

            }
            start = dtNext;
        }
    }

    protected void EventDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(StartDate_TB.Text);
        int n = Int32.Parse(EventDuration_DDL.SelectedItem.ToString());
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            Label NewLabel = new Label();
            NewLabel.ID = "Label" + i;
            var eventDate = dt.AddDays(i); //Calendar1.SelectedDate.Date.AddDays(i);
            NewLabel.Text = eventDate.ToLongDateString();

            CheckBox newcheck = new CheckBox();
            newcheck.ID = "CheckBox" + i;

            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<span class='h1size'>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(NewLabel);
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</span>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div class='make-switch pull-right' data-on='info'>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(newcheck);
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("</div>"));
            this.Labeldiv.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br/>"));
            string script1 = @"<script language=""javascript"">
                    alert('The file you are trying to upload is not a permitted file type!!!');
                    </script>;";
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myJScript1", script1);
        }
    }
```

In EventDuration_DDl_SelectedIndexChanged I have created Checkboxes dynamically..

Now, among them if any one is in 'on' state, then it goes to next step i.e, SlotDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged.... otherwise Message 'No event is selected'...
and same code(SlotDuration_DDL_SelectedIndexChanged) is repeated for all the dates which are in 'on' state.......

How can I do so?????????????

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: updated..... pls see........